# Durbin vs. Breusch-Godfrey test for autocorrelation: which is better?

Tags: regression, time-series, hypothesis-testing, autocorrelation

I'm being asked to justify why I use either the Durbin's alternative test for Serial Correlation or the Breusch-Godfrey test. It seems that both are relatively competent tests however there is little distinction between the two online and which test is better for a given scenario. Are there any thoughts any of you might have?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to the tests' null hypotheses. The Durbin-Watson test only looks at autocorrelation at lag $1$, while the Breusch-Godfrey test looks at all autocorrelations up to lag $h$. If you can rule out autocorrelations beyond order $1$ a priori (which may or may not be the case depending on your application), the Durbin-Watson test will be sufficient. Otherwise, only the Breusch-Godfrey test will provide you the relevant flexibility.

Comment: Yeah I meant Durbins alternative test though, not durbin watson

Comment: @NoobOzy, oh, sorry then. What test do you have in mind exactly? Could you provide a reference?

Comment: ofc https://www.coursehero.com/file/p67mthj/Durbins-alternative-test-is-computed-by-performing-a-Wald-test-to-determine/

Comment: @NoobOzy, cannot quite see the whole thing. A few lines above would be relevant for understanding what those u-hats are.

Comment: Great points, Richard. The OP must be referring to the Durbin h statistic.

Comment: Something else to mention here is that the Durbin-Watson test is invalid in the presence of lagged dependent variables, whereas the Breusch-Godfrey and Durbin h are ok.

Comment: @ColorStatistics, it has been a while since I studied these things. A reference for DW being invalid in presence of lagged DVs would be welcome.

Comment: Davidson & Mackinnon discuss it on page 280; Greene on page 1002, also here on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin%E2%80%93Watson_statistic

Comment: @ColorStatistics, thank you!

Comment: @RichardHardy: You're welcome.